# What would you call this scale?

Tags: theory, scales, terminology

Its basically a Dorian Scale with #4

F G A♭ B C D E♭ F

Don't know what to call it

Comment: This would be in the key of Eb (w/ an accidental, B natural) the relative minor is C and if you look at the pattern the B is the leading tone.  In other words it's just C harmonic minor (starting on the F).  The melodic minor scales all have names like the 7 diatonic modes.  Not sure if the harmonic minor ones do.

Comment: I would call it Ambroz scale! ;) :)

Comment: Is the music _actually limited_ to those tones, or does the `B` change between flat and natural in different passages?

Answer (score 10):

According to [this resource](http://www.huygens-fokker.org/docs/modename.html) with lists of scale/mode names, some terms for this scale (with semitone groupings 2 1 3 1 2 1 2) include:

> Mela Hemavati, Raga Desisimharavam, Maqam Nakriz, Tunisian, Dorian
>   sharp 4, Misheberekh: Jewish, Nigriz, Pimenikos, Souzinak
>   (Peiraiotikos Minor): Greece, Ukrainian Minor, Kaffa, Gnossiennes

[This page](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/1741) suggests the name "Lydian Diminished" (which I personally find to be a curious designation) and has further possible terms and info.

In a normal Western context, I'd agree with Chris Mitchell's idea of Dorian with a sharp 4.

Answer (score 5):

this scale would work over  Minor 7th #11 chords, lets call it Dorian(#4)

Answer (score 5):

This is the the fourth mode of the harmonic minor scale, and is known as the [Ukranian Dorian scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Dorian_scale).

Every time you have a 1 tone and a half jump between two adjacent degrees of a scale (in this case between A♭ and B), you should think of some harmonic minor permutation ;)) - see the more common [phrygian dominant](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/1459).

As mentioned in other answers, more descriptive names may be *dorian #4*, or minor #4 natural6...

One notable use is in Erik Satie's Gnossienne no. 1:

Answer (score 2):

This is the Ukrainian Dorian scale.